# Не находит объект

Tags: javascript, json, api

```
$.get("https://api.worldoftanks.ru/wot/account/tanks/?application_id=не важно8&account_id=" + account_id + "&language=ru", function(data) {
    meta = data.meta.count;
    battles_tank = data.data[account_id].statistics.battles;
    
    /*
    for (var i = 0; i < meta; i++) {
      console.log(battles_tank[i]);
    }
    */
  });
```

Вот данные из JSON

```
{"status":"ok","meta":{"count":1},"data":{"1351837":[{"statistics":{"wins":12,"battles":27},"mark_of_mastery":2,"tank_id":6401}
```

Вот ответ:

```
Cannot read property 'battles' of undefined
```

Comment: `data.data[account_id]` массив

Comment: Исправил, все равно такой же ответ

Comment: Отобразите, пожалуйста, в ответе, как именно исправили.

Comment: Кхм, помогло, спасибо!

Comment: ```battles_tank = data.data[account_id].statistics.battles;``` Вы обращаетесь к ```data[account_id]``` как к объекту хотя это масив. И данные из JSON не соотвествуют JSON формату.

Comment: @Danil22727373 закрывайте вопрос